# Magento2 : How to show country and state dropdown field in customer account information section in admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, drop-downs, countries, state

I want to add country and state dropdown field in account information in Magento2 admin?
Googled a lot, but not able to find right solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using enterprise edition?

Comment: No, I am not using enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

try this Answer `custom customer attributes are not shown at checkout register in Magento 2` just edit 'input' => 'select', in your custom file

Comment: I have already created the country attribute. It appears on the admin, how can I create state to apply country logic. I mean when I change country the respected region should be listed.